# Adjust margins depending on browser's window size

Tags: jquery, css, margin, image-resizing, horizontal-scrolling

I have a series of images in an scrolling horizontal layout. There's a margin between the images. I'm using a jQuery script that takes care of resizing the images depending on the browser's window size. My question is, how can I adjust the margin between the images, too?

I need the design to be totally fluid, so media queries are not a solution in this case.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
    </div> 
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slide"><img src="image01.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="image02.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="image03.jpg" /></div>
        ....
        <div class="slide"><img src="imageN.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slides {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var $window = $(window),
        $header = $('#header'),
        $footer = $('#footer');

    var getHorizontalPageHeight = function () {
        return $window.height() - $header.outerHeight() - $footer.outerHeight();
    };

    var $slides = $('#slides'),
        $items = $slides.find('img, iframe');

    $items.each(function () {
        var $item = $(this),
            width = $item.data('width') || $item.attr('width') || 1,
            height = $item.data('height') || $item.attr('height') || 1;
        $item.data({
            height: height,
            ratio: width / height
        });
    });

    var resizer = function () {

        var contentHeight = getHorizontalPageHeight(),
            windowWidth = $window.width(),
            windowHeight = $window.height();

        $items.each(function () {

            var $item = $(this),
                originalHeight = $item.data('height'),
                height = contentHeight > originalHeight ? originalHeight : contentHeight,
                width,
                ratio = $item.data('ratio');

                width = height * ratio;

                $item.css({
                    width: width,
                    maxWidth: 'none',
                    height: width / ratio
                });

        });

    };

    $window.on('resize', resizer);
    resizer();

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean something like using `@media` queries

Comment: Hi, what about making a fixed width and height for your images. Example <img src="imgpath" style="width:40%;height:auto;"> something like this. and it will auto resize depending on the parent div's dimensions. Most of dev's our there use this approach

Comment: Use css ( @media )

Comment: I want to know that why in your case wouldn't the media queries work? You mention the fluid design that must be held on to, but using media queries wont break that and it is one of the best possible solutions for you these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you don't want to use mediaQ you could use percentage as `margin-right:2%` . that  `2%` depends on resizing the window ( it will get smaller as the window gets smaller )

see here  **[jsfiddle width percentage](https://jsfiddle.net/v965emho/1/)**

code :

```
 .slide {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 2%;
vertical-align: top;
height:100px;
background:red;
width:20%
}
```

OR you could use `vw` which means viewport(window) width. where `100vw` is max and `0vw` min .  so again, that `margin-right:2vw` will increase or decrease depending on the window's width.

see here **[jsfiddle with vw](https://jsfiddle.net/v965emho/2/)**

code :

```
.slide {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 2vw;
vertical-align: top;
height:100px;
background:red;
width:20%
}
```

Let me know if one of these 2 solutions worked for you.

PS : *i've put that `width` and `height` to the `.slide` for example purposes only*

Comment: Using viewport units is a nice solution, thanks. Although, in my case, I'll go with vh units because I need the margins to increase or decrease depending on the window's height.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```